# Wordpress A-Z Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have this one and I dont know where I'm wrong I am not a php coder but I think with a help will work

```
add_action('init', 'set_index_var');
function set_index_var()
{
    global $azindex;
    $tmp = get_query_var('azindex');

    if($tmp != "")
        $azindex = $tmp;
}

//Add WHERE addition to query 
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'azindex_posts_where',10,2 );

function azindex_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $azindex;
    //global $azindextype;

    //var_dump($wpdb);

    if(isset($azindex)  )
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '{$azindex}%' ";

    return $where;
}
/********************************************************************/
/* FILTERS                                                          */
/********************************************************************/
// Add the query var azindex so WP won't drop it
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'azindex_add_query_vars');

function azindex_add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "azindex";
    return $vars;
}
/********************************************************************/
/* MAIN CODE                                                        */
/********************************************************************/
function azindex_get_alphabetical_index(  )
{
    $azindex = get_query_var('azindex');

    if($azindex == '')
        $azindex = -1;

    $base_url = get_permalink(get_the_ID());

    for($i=0;$i<26;$i++)
    {
        $letter[$i] = chr($i + 65);

        $href = $base_url.'index.php?azindex='.$letter[$i];
        $base_add = '';

        if($azindex == "")  //Not selected -> link
            echo '<div><a href="'.$href.'">'.$letter[$i].'</a></div>';
        else if($azindex == $letter[$i])
            echo '<div class="selected" >'.$letter[$i].'</div>';
        else
            echo '<div><a href="'.$href.'">'.$letter[$i].'</a></div>';
    }

    if($azindex == -1)
        echo '<div class="all" >All</div>';
    else
        echo '<div><a href="'.$base_url.'">All</a></div>';
}
```

I can display alphabetic pagination on my index but when I click on an alphabet it allways sends me to the new post single page.
Is there anyway to keep index and display selected alphabet posts instead going to single page?

Answer (score 0):

Now I cahnged that code to:

```
//Register the NUMERIC Index shortcode [numindex]
$numindex = '';

add_shortcode('numindex','numindex_get_filter');
function numindex_get_filter($attr){

    echo '<div class="numindex clearfix">';
    numindex_get_numeric_index(); 
    echo '</div>';
}

/********************************************************************/
/* ACTIONS                                                          */
/********************************************************************/

//Add WHERE addition to query 
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'numindex_posts_where',10,2 );

function numindex_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $numindex;
    //global $numindextype;

    //var_dump($wpdb);

    if(isset($numindex) )
        $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,10}' ";

    return $where;
}
/********************************************************************/
/* FILTERS                                                          */
/********************************************************************/
// Add the query var numindex so WP won't drop it
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'numindex_add_query_vars');

function numindex_add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "numindex";
    return $vars;
}
/********************************************************************/
/* MAIN CODE                                                        */
/********************************************************************/
function numindex_get_numeric_index(  )
{
    $numindex = get_query_var('numindex');

    if($numindex == '')
        $numindex = -1;

    $base_url = get_site_url();

    for($i=0;$i<26;$i++)
    {
        $letter[$i] = chr($i + 65);

        $href = $base_url.'/index.php?numindex='.$letter[$i];
        $base_add = '';

        if($numindex == "") //Not selected -> link
            echo '<div><a href="'.$href.'">'.$letter[$i].'</a></div>';
        else if($numindex == $letter[$i])
            echo '<div class="selected" >'.$letter[$i].'</div>';
        else
            echo '<div><a href="'.$href.'">'.$letter[$i].'</a></div>';
    }

    if($numindex == -1)
        echo '<div class="all" >test</div>';
    else
        echo '<div><a href="'.$base_url.'">test</a></div>';
}
```

It lists me all numeric title posts but now I can get # charachter as link :) it displays me all alphabet.Instead the Alphabet I want to display just one link as 0-9 or #